# Editing HTML in Visual Studio 2012 creates a marker under tags, how do I turn it off?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012, editing

In Visual Studio 2012, when you're editing html in Visual Studio, and your cursor is inside a tag (or more annoyingly, a closing tag), a little underline shows up under the beginning of the (opening) tag.  If you click on it it opens a menu headed with "[tag] Tasks" and, most often, "Format Element."

I hate this thing and am on the verge of violence.  I can't figure out how to turn it off because it has no name and I can't google something up.  Please save me.  How do I turn this off?  Failing that, what is it called?  It's not intellisense or anything else in the "html" part of the text editor options.  I'm pretty sure I've tried them all, but am perfectly willing to be proven wrong.

Comment: can u add more detail or a screen shot of whats happening? Nothing annoyed me when i did. So for a clarification could you do?

Comment: I need a reputation of at least 10 to post an image.  But hopefully this works: http://imgur.com/O0loG9I
I'm referring to the box under the I in INPUT.  I'm willing to accept that this is a personal problem rather than a problem with visual studio, but I'd still like it disabled.  I have a tendency to fidget with my cursor while reading code, which makes that box appear, disappear, jump around, or imitate a cursor and cause me to edit code in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the new Smart Tasks feature and I think we cant turn off: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/whats-new#_Toc318097398